# Mapping int and string values to Map<Integer, List<String>>

Tags: c++, string, sockets, dictionary

In my program I get this sort of result:

```
2:one
3:ff
3:rr
6:fg
```

I want to send this data using send() method in socket so that I can get word occurrence and word at receiving socket.

I think `Map<Integer, List<String>>` would be better option.

My code snippet:

```
   for (std::map < int, std::vector < std::string > >::iterator hit = three_highest.begin(); hit != three_highest.end(); ++hit) {
        //std::cout << hit->first << ":";

        for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator vit = (*hit).second.begin(); vit != (*hit).second.end(); vit++) {
            std::cout << hit->first << ":";
            std::cout << *vit << "\n";
}
}
```

`hit->first` gives occurrence[int val], `*vit` gives string.

How can I store it into : `Map<Integer, List<String>>` for each for iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just construct the lists and insert them into the map.

```
std::map<int, std::list<std::string> > map_to_string_list;

for (auto list_it = three_highest.begin(); list_it != three_highest.end(); ++list_it) {
    map_to_string_list[list_it->first] = std::list<std::string>(list_it->second.begin(),
                                                                list_it->second.end());
}
```

Comment: did you not encounter second part for `vit`

Comment: @Karimkhan This code copies all the values from a `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>>` into a `std::map<int, std::list<std::string>>`. If that's not what you want, could you clarify what exactly you do want?

Comment: Thanks buddy. I want to construct `std::map<int, std::list<std::string> > map_1` which contains `hit->first` and `*vit` as in my code. Actually I want to send this in `send()` method of socket and receive at receiver side!